# android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm not a designer but when i got this project i can`t open specifically some screens, i think that they are screens and we only reuse some of the layouts have been created.
Anyway can somebody help me?
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String imageUrl = ProductsList.get(position).getImage();

```
    holder.itemName.setText(ProductsList.get(position).getName());
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.itemImage);

    holder.parentLayot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public String currentActivity;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
            activity.runOnUiThread(bd);
            String activityName = activity.getClass().getSimpleName();
            // Toast.makeText(activity,ProductsList.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (activityName.equals("Product_View")){
                // Toast.makeText(activity,"Click and pass",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Second_Product_View.class);
                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Second_Product_View")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Third_Product_View.class);

                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_name"));
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_id"));

                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Third_Product_View")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Fourth_Product_View.class);

                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_name"));
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_id"));

                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_name", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_subcategory_name"));
                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_id", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_subcategory_id"));

                intent.putExtra("item_section_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_section_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Fourth_Product_View")){
                holder.downloadManager = (DownloadManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                String file = activity.getString(R.string.base_url) + "files/example-" + ProductsList.get(position).getId() + ".pdf";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                Long reference = holder.downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            } else if (activityName.equals("Formation_View")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Second_Formation_View.class);
                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Second_Formation_View")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Third_Formation_View.class);

                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_name"));
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("item_category_id"));

                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_subcategory_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Third_Formation_View")){
                holder.downloadManager = (DownloadManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                String file = activity.getString(R.string.base_url) + "files/example-" + ProductsList.get(position).getId() + ".pdf";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                Long reference = holder.downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            } else if (activityName.equals("Tools_View")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Second_Tools_View.class);
                intent.putExtra("item_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_name", ProductsList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("item_category_id", ProductsList.get(position).getId());

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } else if(activityName.equals("Second_Tools_View")){
                holder.downloadManager = (DownloadManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                String file = activity.getString(R.string.base_url) + "files/example-" + ProductsList.get(position).getId() + ".pdf";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                Long reference = holder.downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

and the logcat shows this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at
```

Comment: I think your error start at this line `Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();`.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This line is probably the culprit:

> ```
> Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
> ```

The view `v` passed to the `onClick()` method is the same view that you assigned the listener to, so `v` is the same as `holder.parentLayot`. I don't know exactly where `holder.parentLayot` came from, but chances are very good that (in XML) this view (or one of its parents) has an `android:theme` attribute.

When a view has the `android:theme` attribute, it doesn't use its activity's context directly. Instead, the android framework will "wrap" the activity's context in a `ContextThemeWrapper` in order to modify the view's theme.

To access the activity from this wrapper, you'll have to "unwrap" it. Try something like this:

```
private static Activity unwrap(Context context) {
    while (!(context instanceof Activity) && context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }

    return (Activity) context;
}
```

Then, you can use this method in your `onClick()` instead of casting the context directly:

```
Activity activity = unwrap(v.getContext());
```

Comment: I'm new at this, could you explain how can i identificate tHE ContestWrapper? please

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You don't need to "identify" it; `v.getContext()` is returning you a context that is a `ContextThemeWrapper` and also not an `Activity`. The code I posted will unwrap any such context until it finds an activity, so you can just paste it in and it should work.

Comment: Nice explanation!, Several of my coordinatorLayouts were using the app:theme

Comment: The solution is very helpful!

Comment: great it helped

Answer (score 26):

Recursive solution in Kotlin:

```
fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
    return when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        is ContextWrapper -> this.baseContext.getActivity()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Checked with case of using `View.getContext()`.

Answer (score -2):

Simple make use of a context just live this

> FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();