# ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

**Cannot solve as::  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.**

Went through various sites but cannot solve my problem.

```
holder.ivPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                Fragment myFragment = new BookingDetailsFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bookingFragment, myFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();



            }
        });
```

Layout is inflated in this way::

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public BookingActivityAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_booking_data, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640154/android-view-contextthemewrapper-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity)

Comment: @StanislavBondar  actually i am working on replacing fragment, so I followed this answer before posting, but  getSupportFragmentManager() doesnot work by showing red lines errors. Any help will be appreciated. activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bookingFragment, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make use of the following snippet for your issue. But I would like to recommend you do not do so as such for two reasons mainly.

- Since you explicitly need Activity only, why not send that through or even better implement an interface for callback.
- What if tomorrow this will be changed, and there will be other context for `View`?

```java
/**
 * Get activity instance from desired context.
 */
public static Activity getActivity(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return null;
    if (context instanceof Activity) return (Activity) context;
    if (context instanceof ContextWrapper) return getActivity(((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext());
    return null;
}
```

EDIT: Snippets for callback to activity

```java
public interface MyAdapterListener {
        void onPlaceClick();
    }
```

And then when you are creating an instance of your Adapter you can pass it like this

```java
public BookingActivityAdapter(MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener){
        this.myAdapterListener = myAdapterListener;
}
```

Just be sure to implement this interface in your activity. Then finally inside your `onClick` you can use this interface as follows

```java
holder.ivPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myAdapterListener.onPlaceClick();

            }
        });
```

Comment: that's the true case, how should I do with the above code with replacing fragments, because getSupportFragmentManager does not work!! Would u not mind putting some light on it.

Comment: Implement a callback via an interface back to your activity so when you perform a click action it goes back to your activity and from there on you can directly perform transaction. I will add some pseudo  snippets for you in the answer.  @HubbyTiwari.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but I resolved it by passing `MyActivity.this` instead of `this` or `getApplicationContext()`.